# trying to insert document into my collection, but i m getting "errmsg" : "Document failed validation", code: "121"

Tags: mongodb, validation, collections, document, mongo-shell

i am learning MongoDB, I have created a collection and now when i am trying to insert document its showing **"errmsg" : "Document failed validation", code: "121"**

**Following is my collection code:**

```
db.createCollection( "personprofiles", {
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "PersonID", "PersonName", "Gender", "DOB", "Occupation", "Noofchildren", "ProfileType", "Purge" ],
      properties: {
         PersonID: {
            bsonType: "number",
                description: "must be an integer and is required"
         },
         PersonName: {
            bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
         },
         Gender: {
            enum: [ "Male", "Female" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         },
            MartialStatus: {
            enum: [ "Single", "Married" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         },
            DOB : {
                bsonType: "date",
                description: "must be an date and is required"
            },
            Occupation: {
            bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
         },
            Noofchildren: {
            bsonType: "number",
                description: "must be an integer and is required"
         },
            ProfileType: {
            enum: [ "Gymnast", "Judge", "CompetitionDirector", "Organizers", "Coach", "Administrator", "Volunteers" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         },
            Purge: {
            enum: [ "Yes", "No" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         },
            Addresses: {
                bsonType: "array",
                description: "must be an array and is required",
                required: [ "AddressID", "AddressType", "AddressLine1", "AddressLine2", "Area", "Locality","City","State","Country","PostalCode"],
                properties: {
            AddressID: {
                bsonType: "number",
                description: "must be an integer and is required"
                    },
            AddressType: {
            enum: [ "Permanent", "Temporary", "Correspondence", "Office" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values"
         },
            AddressLine1: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is  required"
            },
            AddressLine2: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
            },
            Area: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is  required"
            },
            Locality: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is  required"
            },
            City: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and isrequired"
            },
            State: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
            },
            Country: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
            },
            PostalCode: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be an string and is required"
            }
                }
            },
            ContactNumbers: {
                bsonType: "array",
                description: "must be an array and is required",
                required:[ "ContactID", "ContactType"],
                properties: {
                    ContactID: {
                        bsonType: "number",
                        description: "must be an integer and is required"
                    },
                ContactType: {
            enum: [ "Home", "Mobile", "Office", "CareOf", "Emergency" ],
            description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
         },
            ContactNumber: {
                bsonType: "object",
                description: "must be an string and is required",
                required: ["CountryCode", "RegionCode", "PhoneNumber"],
                properties:{
                    CountryCode: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        pattern: "^[+0-9]{2,4}$",
                        description: "must be an string and is required"
                    },
                    RegionCode: {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        pattern: "^[0-9]{3}$",
                        description: "must be an string and is required"
                    },
                    PhoneNumber:
                    {
                        bsonType: "string",
                        pattern: "^[0-9]{10}$",
                        description: "must be an string and is required"
                    }
                }
            }   
                }
            },
            Email:{
                bsonType: "array",
                description:"must be an array and is required",
                required:["EmailID", "EmailType"],
                properties:{
                    EmailID: {
                        bsonType: "number",
                        description:"must be an integer and is required"
                    },
                    EmailType:{
                        bsonType: "string",
                        pattern : "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$",
                        description: "must be a string and match regular expression pattern"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
   } }
} )
```

**This is the document i am trying to insert**

```
db.personprofiles.insert({
"PersonID": 1001,
"PersonName": "john simon",
"Gender": "Male",
"MartialStatus": "Single",
"DOB": "1997-8-1",
"Occupation": "Service",
"Noofchildren": 0,
"ProfileType": "Administrator",
"Purge": "yes",
"Addresses":[{
    "AddressID": 1,
    "AddressType":"Permanent",
    "AddressLine1": "101/4",
    "AddressLine2":"sundar nagar",
    "Area": "kalina",
    "Locality": "Santacruz(east)",
    "City": "Mumbai",
    "State": "Maharashtra",
    "Country": "India",
    "PostalCode": "400055"
}],
"ContactNumbers": [{
    "ContactID":1,
    "ContactType":"Home",
    "ContactNumber":{
        "CountryCode": "+91",
        "RegionCode": "022",
        "PhoneNumber": "700383555"
    }
}],
Email:[{
    EmailID: 1,
    EmailType: "johnxyz@gmail.com"
}]
})
```

collection has been created successfully, the only issue i am having to insert  a document. Unable to figure out error. 
Someone can help me? Look like i forget something.

Comment: The `Email`, `EmailID` and `EmailType` element names must be surrounded by quotes

Comment: What the guy said above and also make sure that value for "DOB" is actually recognized as a date. "Noofchildren": the value you are passing in is 0, which may be a problem if you are requiring the field (0 is falsy). You are passing "yes" to purge, when the allowed values are "Yes" and "No" (try matching the case, capitalize your 'y').

Also, might I suggest you edit out some of your personal information here? Probably not a good idea to post all of your personal contact information. Unless it is fake information, then: good job.